# How to convert a unicode list of lists to utf8 format in python?

Tags: python, list, csv, unicode

```
with open('assignmentTest.csv', 'wb') as finale:
    writer = csv.writer(finale) #creates csv file to write final lists into
    finalRows = zip(firstName, lastName, phdName, universityName, departmentName) #put all of the lists into another lists so that the outputs are in 'column form' as opposed to rows
    for rowToken in finalRows: #puts each element of each list together in the same order
        writer.writerow(rowToken)
```

I'm trying to find the efficient way to convert the list of lists into `utf8` format while not messing with my `writer.writerow(rowToken)` - Basically what I'm using to make separate columns for the lists.

Comment: Have you considered just converting each element? Also, if you have an input file, you should consider using that file object as generator instead of reading its content into a list that is then processed and written sequentially again.

Comment: why are you passing 'b' mode to open?

Comment: I tried converting each element, but just the same error.

Comment: @ChadS., `b` is required for `csv.reader` or `csv.writer` on platforms where it makes a difference (Windows).  See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.reader).

Answer (score 0):

@DimitrisJim's now deleted answer was correct.  Did you accidently use `writerows` instead of `writerow`?

```
#!python2
#coding:utf8

import csv

firstName = u'John Joe 马克'.split()
lastName = u'Doe Blow 多路能'.split()
phdName = u'a b c'.split()
universityName = u'd e f'.split()
departmentName = u'g h i'.split()

with open('assignmentTest.csv', 'wb') as finale:
    writer = csv.writer(finale) #creates csv file to write final lists into
    finalRows = zip(firstName, lastName, phdName, universityName, departmentName) #put all of the lists into another lists so that the outputs are in 'column form' as opposed to rows
    for rowToken in finalRows: #puts each element of each list together in the same order
        writer.writerow([col.encode('utf8') for col in rowToken])
```

Output file content encoded in UTF-8:

```
John,Doe,a,d,g
Joe,Blow,b,e,h
马克,多路能,c,f,i
```